# Use django-filters instead model.objects.filter

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-filter, django-filters

My question is how the following query in Django to make it using the [django-filters](http://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html)?

```
Schedule.objects.filter(Q(room_id__number__icontains=get_request['room']) |  \
                                        Q(room_id__name__icontains=get_request['room']), \
                                        (Q(subject_id__full_name__icontains=get_request['subject']) |  \
                                        Q(subject_id__short_name__icontains=get_request['subject'])),
                                        (Q(teacher_id__name__icontains=get_request['teacher']) | \
                                        Q(teacher_id__short__icontains=get_request['teacher']))
                                   )
```

What I have so far is as follows.The problem is that these fields do not have it and `room_id__name,  teacher_id__short,  subject_id__short_name`. I just want to make subject OR request, but do not know how it works using django-filters

```
class ScheduleFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    room = django_filters.CharFilter(name='room_id__number', lookup_type='icontains')
    subject = django_filters.CharFilter(name='subject_id__full_name', lookup_type='icontains')
    teacher = django_filters.CharFilter(name='teacher_id__number', lookup_type='icontains')

    class Meta: 
        model = Schedule
        fields = ['room', 'subject', 'teacher']
```